# CSS rule overridden... but also not

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I have a CSS rule which (from the look of the page) is working. However, when I look in the inspector, it's crossed out.

[image: cross-out rule]

However, when I look at "Computed Styles," it seems like the rule is indeed styling the page, not being overridden at all!

[image]

Can anyone explain this discrepancy? Thanks!

Comment: Make a JSFiddle or something

Comment: the webkit version is crossed ... am sure there is the standard one somewhere else

Comment: It might be a sourcemap bug

Comment: Hi Katie, we need to see the website at least, preferably a reproducible code demo here in the question. We can't help much just by seeing a screenshot of one selector.

Comment: Okay, I’ll try to reproduce in a fiddle when I get a chance. Site is work site. If any of you happen to use Sentry (which you all should!), you can see it as the background of any modal in your dashboard.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - no, actually, there isn't a standard one elsewhere. The selector in question is the very top one, right under `element.style`.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, I made [a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GGPoQr) based on the OP's screenshot, and the property does appear crossed out in the inspector, even though it works as designed.

Comment: I guess nobody noticed this anomaly before, because everybody always follows this rule with an unprefixed `filter` one and then the webkit one is naturally crossed out. I mean, everybody does, don't they?

Comment: is the filter actually applied on the page?

Comment: @MrLister intresting ... so this for sure a bug in the dev tool of chrome then?

Comment: @MrLister - thanks for makin g that! (didn't realize it would be that easy to reproduce) Also, no, we don't have a non-webkit one. Maybe we should...

Comment: @Anthony yes, the blur applies (see "a CSS rule which (from the look of the page) is working" above)

Comment: but the grayscale doesn't?

Comment: @Anthony Can you see the screenshots in the OP's question? That's what the question is about. And can you see the codepen in action?

Comment: @MrLister yes, i can. that's precisely why i'm asking